# Given two rotational angles, how do I calculate an orbital position?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, 3d

I'm moving around a satellite around another object in 3D space by adjusting two rotational angles - rotation about the X and Y axes of the tracked object. How do I calculate the objects final position given those angles and a radius?

This works fine for just the y-axis rotation:

```
position.x = otherObject.position.x + Math.cos(yRotation) * radius;
position.y = otherObject.position.y;
position.z = otherObject.position.z + Math.sin(yRotation) * radius;
```

But as soon as I try and incorporate the x-axis rotation, things get weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being using a transformation matrix calculated from the rotational angles, as such:

```
var mtx = new THREE.Matrix4();
mtx.rotateY(yRotation);
mtx.rotateX(xRotation);
var v = new THREE.Vector3(mtx.elements[8], mtx.elements[9], mtx.elements[10]);
v.multiplyScalar(radius);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate something in 2D using these equations (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29)):

```
x' = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
y' = x * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle)
```

You can use basically the same equations for rotating about the x/y/z axes in 3D, eg for rotating about the y axis:

```
x' = x * cos(angle) - z * sin(angle)
y' = y
z' = x * sin(angle) + z * cos(angle)
```

I think what you want to do is:

- Rotate by yRotation about the y axis
- Then rotate by xRotation about the x axis

You've already done the y axis rotation. So starting with (x, y, z) = (radius, 0, 0), you've done:

```
x' = x * cos(angley) - z * sin(angley) = radius * cos(angley)
y' = y = 0
z' = x * sin(angley) + z * cos(angley) = radius * sin(angley)
```

We just have to apply the equations again to rotate about the x axis:

```
x'' = x' = radius * cos(angley)
y'' = y' * cos(anglex) - z' * sin(anglex) = -radius * sin(angley) * sin(anglex)
z'' = y' * sin(anglex) + z' * cos(anglex) = radius * sin(angley) * cos(anglex)
```

Note that adjusting the "y axis" rotation won't necessarily rotate the satellite about the y axis (eg if your x rotation is 90 degrees, then adjusting the y rotation will actually rotate about the z axis). If you don't like this behaviour, I would suggest just storing the satellite (x, y, z) (relative to the tracked object) and adjusting that directly (you'll probably want to re-normalise after each adjustment to ensure floating point inaccuracy doesn't make your satellite drift away).

Comment: Am I understanding you correct if I think you're saying the calculations should be:

  position.x = otherObject.position.x + Math.cos(yRotation) * radius;
  position.y = otherObject.position.y - Math.sin(yRotation) * Math.sin(xRotation);
  position.z = otherObject.position.z + Math.sin(yRotation) * Math.cos(xRotation) * radius;

?

If so, that doesn't work either. I can post the full code somewhere if that helps to understand the problem.

Comment: Correction:


  position.x = otherObject.position.x + Math.cos(yRotation) * radius;
  position.y = otherObject.position.y - Math.sin(yRotation) * Math.sin(xRotation) * radius;
  position.z = otherObject.position.z + Math.sin(yRotation) * Math.cos(xRotation) * radius;

Still doesn't work...

Comment: @korona Yes, that's what I was saying. I struggle to see why that "doesn't work" -- I believe it's essentially the same as the solution you've posted, with a couple of minor differences: yours starts with (x, y, z) = (0, 0, radius) rather than (radius, 0, 0); yours rotates by x first (you're doing outv = RY * RX * inv); your x rotation is in the opposite direction.